# Bluetooth SPP (Serial Port Protocol) and Cobra Tag

Tags: serial, bluetooth, protocol, android

I have been trying to build something similar to the [Cobra Tag](http://www.engadget.com/2011/08/30/cobra-tag-review/) (Check out the video). I have written a prototype android app which uses SPP to connect to a bluetooth module and exchange commands, which is working great. But, i have a few queries

- From what appears, does Cobra Tag also use SPP or any proprietary custom profile ?
- I am able to connect to a single device over SPP and do the data exchange, how do i go about connecting to multiple devices simultaneously. Does Bluetooth/SPP support that ?
- Should i be using any other bluetooth profile/protocol which would be more efficient for this purpose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Cobra Tags [FAQ](http://cobratag.com/faqs/)

*Answer to first and second question.*

> *Can I use a Cobra or other manufacturer’s Bluetooth headset for
> handsfree talking while using this product?*
>
> Yes you can. The Cobra Tag uses a different Bluetooth communication
> link than the headsets (called **serial port profile**) so they can both
> work together.

> *How many Cobra Tags can be connected to one mobile phone?*
>
> The maximum number with some phones is 7. The maximum number that can
> be paired with iOS devices is 1. This is based on a technology
> limitation. It seems that some phones can’t simultaneously handle 7
> Tags and are better off with 1-5 maximum.

*Answer to Third question.*

SPP emulates a serial cable to provide a simple substitute for existing RS-232. Architecture of cobra tag shows it doesn't need complex data manipulation and just requires a few set of commands for its operation. I'll suggest sticking to this profile only.